# Why do we say that the torque on Earth due to Sun is zero?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque, earth, solar-system

Let's assume, the mass of Earth = $M$, the radius of Earth = $r$, the moment of inertia due to revolution of Earth = $I$, angular momentum due to the revolution = $L$, distance between the center of Earth and Sun = $R$, the angular velocity of Earth due to its revolution around the sun = $\omega$

According to the parallel axis theorem, $I = \frac{2}{5}Mr^2 + MR^2$

So, $$L = I\omega$$
$$= \frac{2}{5}Mr^2\omega + MR^2\omega$$
$$= \frac{2}{5}Mr^2R^2\omega\cdot\frac{1}{R^2} + MR^2\omega$$

According to Kepler's second law of planetary motion, the **constant** areal velocity of Earth = $\frac{1}{2}R^2\omega$

Hence, $$L = \frac{p}{R^2} + q$$
where, p and q both stays **constant** over time.

Since $R$ changes over time, $L$, the angular momentum is not conserved.
Rather, it's a quadratic function of $\frac{1}{R}$

So why do we say that the torque acting on Earth due to Sun is $0$ when the angular momentum is **not conserved**?

Comment: I have deleted my answer because I don't think I have explained myself very well. When I have more time I'll make the answer better.

Comment: @BioPhysicist [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) I think, there is no such requirement of using parallel axis theorem (like, every point must stay equidistant from the axis). If the points of a body stay equidistant from the axis, why even bother using this theorem!! Please explain this when u have time

Comment: What is really conserved is the full angular momentum. Kepler's Law just assumes that $(r/R)^2$ is negligible.

Comment: @Felipe What does **full** angular momentum even mean! If u r trying to say that $\frac{1}{R^2}$ is almost zero (since R is so huge), then keep in mind that we are scaling   $\frac{1}{R^2}$ with $p = \frac{2}{5}Mr^2R^2\omega$, So $\frac{p}{R^2}$ is not negligible at all! This will evaluate very different value at perihelion and aphelion!

Comment: The full angular momentum is the one you calculated. Just write it in a more appropriate form: $L=MR^2\omega\left[1+ \frac 25 \left(\frac rR\right)^2\right]$. The term $(r/R)^2$ is of order $10^{-9}$ which I would say is negligible.

Comment: @Felipe Who gets to tell what is appropriate and what is not. Let's not approximate anything. If we want to calculate the **really really full** angular momentum then, we find a non zero torque.

Comment: Let's not approximate anything. Then Kepler's Law does not hold. The quantity conserved is $R^2\omega\left[1+\frac 25\left(\frac rR\right)^2\right]$, not $R^2\omega$ (Kepler).

Comment: @Felipe So I believe,  u can show how Kepler's law doesn't hold? and please,  elaborate on why u think the latter is conserved

Comment: The latter expression in Felipe's comment is conserved because of the conservation of angular momentum of the Earth-Sun system. No, this isn't a circukar definition. The fundamental correct law in this case is angular momentum conservation. Kepler's law is just an approximation. So we can't derive angular momentum conservation from Kepler's laws, instead it's the other way round, conserving angular momentum to derive Kepler's laws.

Comment: BowlOfRed's answer says what I was trying to say a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel axis theorem is for the rotation of a body about a single axis that does not pass through the center of mass.

But the earth's motion cannot be simply described in this way in the frame where the sun is at rest.   It is more usually described as a combination of rotation and orbital movement, where each of these motions has different angular speeds.   Because earth's rotational speed is not equal to $\omega$, the stated equation does not match.  If it were true, then the earth would have the same angular momentum regardless of the rotational speed (since that parameter does not appear).  Two identical orbits with different rotational speed must have different angular momenta.

We can instead sum the rotational and orbital angular momenta into the similar formula:

$$L = L_{\text{rot}} + L_{\text{orbit}} = \frac 25 Mr^2\omega_{\text{rot}} + MR^2\omega_{\text{orbit}}$$

When this formula is manipulated, allowing $\omega_{\text{rot}}$ to remain constant, the angular momentum also remains constant.

Answer (score 1):

Torque on earth due to sun is 0 as gravitational force always acts towards center.

In  the formula of torque of torque which is $\tau = \ rF sin\theta$. Now $\theta$  becomes 0 as Force and r vector acts on same line (r is perpendicular distance from the force F)and hence overall torque becomes 0. As net torque is 0 about earth's center, therefore angular momentum is conserved at center only.

And i don't see why did you parallel axis theorem ?

The angular momentum of earth around sun is just $Mr^2\omega$(R =radius of earth) as rotation of earth on it's own axis is caused by moon and not by sun.
Kepler law states $T^2$ is proportional to $r^3$.
Hence to calculate time period of earth around sun you only need to consider I = M$r^2$
Also note r is usually taken to be $\frac{Apogee+Perigee}{2}$

Comment: How is $r$ zero? And the moment of inertia of a point mass is $Mr^2$. The inertia of earth (a solid sphere) cant be the same. To find the moment of inertia of a solid sphere around an axis outside the body, we must integrate all the moment of inertia of all points of Earth, hence the parallel axis theorem. Just because I am using parallel axis theorem, does not mean I am talking about the rotation around Earth's own axis, Rather it is the proper way to calculate the moment of inertia of a solid sphere, no matter whether its rotating around its own axis or not

Comment: @ImtiazKabir I edited my answer.

Comment: It's an elliptical orbit. In a circular orbit, the tangent of any point on the perimeter is perpendicular to the radius. According to Kepler's first law, the orbit is **elliptical**. So the tangent is not necessarily perpendicular to the radius. And thus r is not perpendicular to F

Comment: @ImtiazKabir Gravitational force will still acts towards center. We are only concerned about torque at the center  hence r =0

Comment: I also agree that the force acts towards center. Yet  $r$ is not $0$. (And please try to understand that $r$ being perpendicular and $r$ being $0$ are 2 different things)

Comment: @Imtiaz Kabir It's $F \sin \theta$ which is $0$ because ,$\theta =0$, $r$ is not $0$

Comment: @maverick Yes you r right , i am sorry.I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @maverick Okay, I will think about that. Can u explain, where my calculation is wrong?

Comment: you said, The angular momentum of earth around sun is just $MR^2\omega$. (R =radius of earth).  How is it true!? u r talking about the revolution of Earth around Sun, but considering only the radius of Earth when trying to calculate angular momentum! Also, Can u explain, what u mean by "rotation of Earth on it's own axis is caused by moon and not hy sun"! I think this rotation is there because Earth was born rotating!  You could have said that, this rotation is affected by moon, but then you cant neglect Sun on that regard.  N.B.: I was never talking about Earth's rotation around its own axis

Comment: @ImtiazKabir  That was a typo . I apologize for my mistake about that r. For calculating time period i have wriiten what r should be. Now every planet  rotates about the combine COM. Now the combine COM of moon and earth lie inside the earth therefore revolution of earth around it's own axis is caused by moon. That is how moon rotate around the earth.  Now the mass of sun is very large. Similarly earth becomes like moon in the case of sun and thus earth revolves around sun.